# save union (merging) command directly in new database

Tags: database, sqlite, save, union

Does anyone have an idea how if we could get the results of a "union" sqlite3 command and stock the returning database directly in a new database object?

For ex.:

we have table 1 (t1) in database 1 and table 2 (t2) in database 2.

Command tool:

```
sqlite> select * from t1 union select * from t2;
```

It prompts the new table in the command line tool but I cannot figure out how to stock the results in a new database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE t3(...);
INSERT INTO t3 SELECT * FROM t1 UNION SELECT * FROM t2;
```

Or if you don't care about column types and constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE t3 AS SELECT * FROM t1 UNION SELECT * FROM t2;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Did not figure out that it was already referring to the main database. And do you know the easiest way to create a script containg all the commands? Is it using python for example?

Comment: I mean if I want to automate everything, like as follows: 1) $ sqlite3 newDB.data; 2) sqlite> attach database 'test.db' as db01;
sqlite> attach database 'test2.db' as db02;
sqlite> create table t3 as select * from t1 union select * from t2;
sqlite>

Comment: You might want to read the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html), or ask a new question.